# Unexpected end of JSON input after cache cleaned

Tags: magento2, javascript, json, magento-2.1.9

I am always getting an `Unexpected end of JSON input` error after clearing my caches `cache:clean | cache:flush`.
But this error **only** happens on first page load.
When I reload the page again it is gone.

Here are some details:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at callback ((index):464)
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1651)
    at Module.check (require.js:867)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1114)
    at require.js:133
    at require.js:1157
    at each (require.js:58)
    at Module.emit (require.js:1156)
    at Module.check (require.js:918)
```

I couldnt figure out from where its coming. Does anyone of you has an idead how to fix this or what is causing the error?

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem, and I identified that

I had left some cms block with the field

```
data-mage-init = {
```

that is,

```
without closing the tag } json
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This solution is helpful to me.